# Why is video sequencer render different for 100% resolution and 80% or lower aspect ratio

Tags: video-sequence-editor

I'm doing a video edit on several screen capture videos with 1920x1080 resolution so no problem with the video size since it is the same setting as in blender output. I do alot of zoom in/out and position transform animations in blender of the videos to give focus on certain parts of the video. In addition, i set the transform origin differently for each clip depending on how i will zoom it. For example, if i need to zoom the left part of the video, it makes sense to have this clip have an origin of (0.0,1.0) and if i have a clip that zooms focus into the center, it makes sense for me to let the clip have a transform origin of (0.5,0.5). I'm not sure though if that is good practice and if i should have the same origin for every clip in the video. I have a hunch that this might be causing this bug.

I noticed that when i render with resolution percentage 100%, it renders exactly like in the video sequencer preview like this:

[image]

but when i set the resolution lower like 80%, the output is shifted, in this case the rescaled video is shifted to the left and lower:

And also i've noticed that some frames in the video when rendered at 30%, don't display at all if not set to 100%.

[image]

Comment: Yeah, I'm not exactly sure what the problem is but I have had issues with messing with the origin of the clip and transforming it. I remember at the time I couldn't tell if the problem was a bug or something I did but I ended up just setting it to it's default and redoing the zoom keyframes. Maybe it is a bug. You could probably report it  as such.

Comment: I agree, this seems to be a bug. Consider reporting it here: https://developer.blender.org/